# In-app only notifications / interactive toasts

Tags: android, toast, android-notifications

Our Android app currently has a large number of dialog and alert boxes.  I'd like to switch these to toasts, but there's a problem - some of them require the user to choose whether to view more info or just dismiss the popup.  It doesn't look like there's a way to do this with toasts.

Is there any existing Android library that supports tappable toasts (i.e., you tap it and it triggers a function call to a listener in the app, sort of like a notification)?  If not, is there a recommended alternative for this "tap-here-to-do-something-otherwise-I'll-just-vanish-in-a-few-seconds" UI pattern, or should I just roll my own fragment class for it?

Comment: Hi I'm not quite sure.. but did you try the custom-toast-view~? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

Comment: That creates a custom layout, not custom interaction.

Comment: I have done the similar thing using a dialog. You can read Toast source code, and copy the WindowParams, which will get you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have to do something similar to my app so I wrote, [DropViewNotification](https://github.com/zodio/DropViewNotification), a boiler plate to make it happen by animating the so-called notification into the screen. It doesn't do automatic dismiss as this should only act as a tool.

It accept any kind of view to make it versatile as I need to put at least two or three obvious view into it (TextView, ProgressBar, ImageView). You can switch it's content on the fly if you want to. Animation can also be customized for both showing and dismissing of the notification and the main content.

In real-life you might want to consider adding controller class to handle the display of the content and auto dismissal, etc. Hope it's of some use to you.